# Did I just accidentally force someone to associate their account?

Tags: support, bounty

I had a bounty on a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107658/what-is-the-benefit-of-becoming-a-neutron-star/128476#128476) that a relatively new user posted an excellent answer for.

After awarding the bounty, I noticed that his rep went up by 200 instead of the bounty amount of 100.

After looking at his rep page, I saw this:

> +130   35 secs ago     4 events     What is the benefit of becoming a neutron star?
>   +100    35 secs ago     assoc   Association Bonus

Did I just accidentally force him to associate accounts somehow?  Is this intended behavior?

Comment: Thanks for the boost!

Comment: @ken.ganong no problem, thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Association Bonus" is a **100 rep** bonus given to all site accounts of a given network user, if the user has more than **200 rep** on any site throughout the network. This is to unlock basic privileges without extensive participation.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Yes, this means that as soon as you reach 200 rep on your first and possibly only site on the network, you still get a +100 bump just for being awesome.